# React does not re-render when state changes if the control buried in an array

Tags: reactjs, state, rerender

I have to generate various controls dynamically according to an xml file. When I add different controls into an array named Items, and then wrap the various control array Items within the dialog control, for example

```
this.dialogPanelInstance = <Dialog visible={this.state.visible}>{items}</Dialog>;
```

If I put this.dialogPanelInstance in the render method, the visibility of dialog will be not re-rendered when state.visibile is changed, same as the visibility of the controls within the Items array.

If I write the line directly in the render method

```
<Dialog visible={this.state.visible}>{items}</Dialog>
```

The dialog is open and closed reflecting to the Visible state but the visibility of controls within is still not responding to the state.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you assigning :

```
this.dialogPanelInstance = <Dialog visible={this.state.visible}>{items}</Dialog>;
```

If it is not within the render method, then the state or prop change will not reflect in `this.dialogPanelInstance` variable, as it does not know it has to update itself. Only the render method and certain other react lifecycle methods are rerun during a state / prop change.

Comment: Yes, after I moved the definition to render method, it works as expected. thanks so much